# Debugging in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, debugging, django-rest-framework, built-in

i am using vs code
How to correctly catch breakpoints in Django REST Framework debugging session after an HTTP request? When debugging a DRF project

breakpoints trigger upon initiating the debug process rather than after sending an HTTP request.

i set "justMyCode": false rather than to true
When I begin the debugging process, all steps are debugged up to the point where the WSGI server starts, as indicated by the following output:

```
sql
Copy code
...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 13, 2024 - 02:36:24
Django version 5.0.3, using settings 'tuto.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

However, after sending an HTTP request, I immediately receive the response, with no breakpoints being hit during the process.